# If the most likely value is that which minimizes squared-error, what are the possible distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, mse

Gauss uniquely characterised the 1D normal distribution by asking for a distribution that:

1. is symmetric
2. is decreasing on either side of some center point $\mu$
3. has the data likelihood maximized by moving the center $\mu$ to be the value that minimizes the sum of square distances of the data points to $\mu$, (i.e. when setting $\mu$ to be the mean of the data).

In many machine learning settings, we have a scalar output $t$ which we optimize under the pretence of maximum likelihood by minimizing mean-squared-error loss and using this value at inference time; in effect, this is assuming (3) above and that the probability at $t$ is the maximum.

Are there any common distributions other than the normal distribution that satisfy (3), but don't satisfy one or both of (1) and (2)?

Comment: Try the following (this is R but the same idea will work in whatever you prefer): `y=rpois(10,5);mean(y);glm(y~1,family=poisson())$fitted`. Try the same with gamma, inverse gamma, binomial, etc.  Note that glms are producing the MLE of the conditional mean as fitted values -- which for `~1` is just the sample mean -- which is of course the minimizer of squared error; note that the link doesn't matter. So the exponential dispersion family is the obvious candidate.

Comment: It might be worth investigating the connection to the  Pitman–Koopman–Darmois theorem.